# node js updated. fetch not working. terminal shows data, browser console does not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been really struggling with a project for an online course.  I'm trying to make an API call and then fetch the data but it isn't working.  I can see the data in my server's terminal and when I go to the endpoint /sentiment I can also see all the data.  If I go to the endpoint and then back to the page with the form and resubmit I see all the data in the console and the page is updated correctly.  The problem is that the data is not being fetched and returned immediately.  This is the relevant code:

index.js (server side):

```
var path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const mockAPIResponse = require('./mockAPI.js');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('dist'))

dotenv.config();
console.log(`Your API key is ${process.env.API_ID}`);

console.log(__dirname)

projectData = {};

url = {};

const AYLIENTextAPI = require('aylien_textapi');

let textapi = new AYLIENTextAPI({
    application_id: process.env.API_ID,
    application_key: process.env.API_KEY,
})


let apiCall = async (url) => {
    textapi.sentiment({
        'url': url
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error === null) {
            projectData = response;
            console.log(projectData);
        }else{
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
};

app.route('/sentiment')
    .get(getData)
    .post(getURL)


function getData(req, res){
    //JSON.stringify(projectData);
    res.status(200).send(projectData)
    console.log(projectData)
};

app.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        console.log(process.env);
        res.sendFile('dist/index.html', { root: __dirname + '/,'})
        res.status(200).json(projectData)
    })
    .post(getSentiment);

function getSentiment(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    projectData = req.body;
    console.log(projectData);
    res.status(200).json(projectData);
};

const port = 8000;

// designates what port the app will listen to for incoming requests
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Example app listening on ${port}`)
})



app.post('/postURL', getURL);

function getURL(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    url = req.body.data;
    console.log(url)
    apiCall(url)
    .then(res.status(200).json(projectData))
}
```

I've tried

```
res.status(200).json(projectData)
```

and

```
res.status(200).send(projectData)
```

and both return an undefined object in the browser console.

formHandler.js:

```
import { postURL } from "./postURL"
import { updateUI } from "./updateUI"



function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    // check what text was put into the form field
    let url = document.getElementById('URL').value
    postURL('/sentiment', url)
    .then(updateUI());
};

export { handleSubmit }
```

my mentor told me to change

```
.then(updateUI())
```

to

```
.then(updateUI)
```

but that doesn't seem to call the function.

I've also tried:

```
postURL('/postURL', url)
```

and get the same result.

postURL.js:

```
import { apiCall } from "./apiCall"
import { updateUI } from "./updateUI"

let postURL = async(url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( { data} ),
    });
    try {
        updateUI()
    }catch(error){
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

export { postURL }
```

updateUI.js:

```
const updateUI = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('/sentiment');
    console.log(res);
    try {
        console.log(res.data)
        const allData = await res.json();
        console.log(allData)
        document.getElementById("polarity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
        document.getElementById("polarityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        document.getElementById("subjectivity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
        document.getElementById("subjectivityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        return allData
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};

export { updateUI }
```

console.log(res) returns this:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8000/sentiment", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:8000/sentiment"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
__proto__: Response
```

I'm really beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why I can see the data in the server terminal and also when I go to /sentiment in the browser but no matter what I try I cannot fetch the data from the endpoint.  I cannot tell you how much I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Thanks alot,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I needed to move the apiCall function directly into my /postURL route.

```
app.post('/postURL', getURL);

function getURL(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    url = req.body.data;
    console.log(url)
    textapi.sentiment({
        'url': url
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error === null) {
            projectData = response;
            console.log(projectData);
            res.send(projectData)
        }else{
            projectData = {polarity: 'enter a valid URL', polarity_confidence: 'enter a valid URL', subjectivity: 'enter a valid URL', subjectivity_confidence: 'enter a valid URL'}
            console.log(error)
            res.send(projectData)
        }
    })
}
```